# C++ Win32 Project in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I want to create a C++ Win32 Application project in Visual Studio 2008, but I don't have that option (as in comparison to Visual Studio 6.0). How can I get that option back or create an equivalent project?

The Option in VS 6.0 looks like this:
[image]

Whereas it's missing in VS 2008:

[image]

Comment: I'm not familar with VS 6 but I'm pretty sure the equivalent in VS 2008 is "Win32 Project".

Answer (score 0):

In VS 2008, choose the "Win32 Project" wizard to generate the equivalent of a VS 6 "Win32 Application".